# Bijection between forests and skew SYT + Cyclic sieving

Tags: co.combinatorics, young-tableaux, catalan-numbers, q-analogs

Consider the two-row skew shape $\lambda_n = (2n+1,n)/(1)$.
The number of standard Young tableaux of this shape is
$\binom{3n}{n}-\binom{3n}{n-2}$ (since one can easily biject this to the set of non-skew shape $(2n+1,n)$, see [A026004](https://oeis.org/A026004) in the OEIS.

Let us now consider the $q$-analog $Y_n(q):= \sum_{T \in SYT(\lambda_n)} q^{maj(T)}$.
By a result in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1017/fms.2021.11), we know that there is some cyclic group $C_n$ of order $n$ acting on $SYT(\lambda_n)$  such that $(SYT(\lambda_n),C_n,Y_n(q))$ satisfies [the cyclic sieving phenomenon](https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/cyclic-sieving.htm).

**Now for the interesting observation:** $Y_n(1)$ counts the number of non-crossing forests with exactly two trees, on $n+2$ vertices. This set also satisfies a cyclic sieving phenomenon under rotation, see [this paper by S. Kluge](https://doi.org/10.37236/2419). Note that this is a cyclic group action of order $n+2$.

By computer experiments, it seems that the $q$-analog $Y_n(q)$ evaluates to the
same values at $n+2$th roots of unity the $q$-analog on non-crossing forests considered by Kluge:
$$
NCF_{n+2,2}(q) = \frac{[n+2]}{[2n+2]} \binom{3n+1}{n}_q.
$$

**Conjecture:** if $\xi$ is either an $n$th root of unity OR an $(n+2)$th root of unity,
then $Y_n(\xi) = NCF_{n+2,2}(\xi)$. I think this should be straightforward to prove by using results [from this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.01362), combined with the [q-Lucas theorem](https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/q-analogues.htm#prelimQanalogsQLucas).

**Question:** Can one find a bijection showing that the set of non-crossing forests with 2 trees on $n+2$ vertices is equal to the number of SYTs of shape $\lambda_n$?
The cyclic group action of order $n+2$ (rotation) on non-crossing forests, what does this correspond to on the SYTs?

Motivation: the previously known cyclic sieving results on SYTs have order $n$,
where $n$ usually is a divisor of the number of boxes in the shape. (The group action, if known, is the promotion operator.)
Establishing a bijection above, would give a more exotic example, where the fake-degree polynomial $Y_n$ is now evaluated at $n+2$th roots of unity instead.

Comment: Regarding the last comment about CSPs for different order actions with the same polynomial, note that the q-Catalan numbers have at least 3 different orders you can get CSPs with: rotation of noncrossing matchings, rotation of triangulations, and "noncrossing (1,2)-matchings" https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03999.

Comment: @SamHopkins Yeah, for Catalan objects, there is really no end to the different CSP instances: https://doi.org/10.5070/c61055513